# Script can't get elements on page load JS

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this code:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
/
```

when page is fully loaded, the class name ("collapsible") is not yet present in the page code, its been loading from remote source only upon user request, so, long story short - its not working.

Lazy solution is to include this code in every page with custom class names, but I don't want it to be this way

Also if its possible I want to stick with this JS code, not jQuery

Can somebody help me to modify this code to work in this case?

Loader for remote content (Update 1):

```js
$.get('t.html', {}, function(data) {
      var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
      var $div1 = $response.find('#div1');
      $('#div-for-remote-content').append($div1);
    },'html');
```

// Update 2

Thank You everyone for your help, I know exactly what I need to solve this problem, but I need your help on that:)

I need a script that checks if all .get() request on page is successfully completed and all content are loaded in main document, if it does, load a script files to the main document.

I have a follow up here, does the scripts in this files will be automatically working on main document?

Comment: Use event delegation.

Comment: I'm new to JS, can you please elaborate, or show me how it needed to be done? @Xufox

Comment: Have you assigned this class to any element in your page, and if yes, where does this code reside in relation to the first occurrence of an element of class "collapsible"?

Comment: Make sure your `<script>` element is located just prior to `</body>` so that it doesn't execute until after the DOM is ready.

Comment: The code is in separate file, at the bottom of main page before closing body tag. Only remote content contains this class name, so this class name not present in main page on main page load @Robidu

Comment: @ScottMarcus That won’t solve the issue. The elements are loaded after a server request; they won’t be in the DOM at all, when the script runs.

Comment: Then you need to ensure that this code is run only after the remote content has been fetched. Btw: How are you retrieving said remote resources? Please edit that into your question as it would help clarify things.

Comment: @AndrewK In your case, event delegation would basically look like this: `document.addEventListener("click", function(e){ if(e.target.hasClass("collapsible")){` _your event listener code_ `} });`, but replace each `this` by `e.target`. This way, it doesn’t matter when the elements appear, and you’re only binding a single event listener.

Comment: By jQuery .get(), the get only occurs if user "requested" this content, in other case it won't be loaded at all @Robidu

Comment: I can't just add this script inside remote content because it will cause duplicate scripts (when user request not just one but several remote pages) and this will cause problems on main page @Robidu

Comment: It would nonetheless be extremely helpful to see the control logic that triggers the `GET` action. Maybe that provides the all-important hint that makes your code work after retrieving the new content.

Comment: It looks really promising, can you modify my code with yours and put it as an answer, please? As I say, I'm new to this staff @Xufox

Comment: Alternative is make the query after you insert the external html

Comment: @Andrew K: As a hint, I'd recommend that you try to apply the suggested modifications yourself (Xufox has provided a possible method) and see if you can get it to work. That would be the best way to learn more about this subject, because by trying things out you are actually getting a feel for things. Should you still meet failure, you can edit a follow-up into your question so that we can inspect the new solution that you may have come up with.

Comment: The question is updated, the "loading code" now is present

Comment: Looks like JQuery. Would a native solution using AJAX suffice? I only need to know whether or not plain HTML is returned.

Comment: Yes, this is jQuery @Robidu

Comment: I have come up with a solution that should satisfy your needs and also uses native JS only.

Comment: I updated the question, now it reflects my current situation

Answer (score 1):

If you have no idea regarding when and how the class 'collapsible' is added to your DOM, you might want to consider using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface, which provides the ability to watch exactly for changes being made to the DOM tree.

For example:

```
// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible').length > 0) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE !!!
        this.disconnect();
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
// this is targeting the whole html tree, you can narrow it if you want
var targetNode = document.documentElement;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

};

In this way, your code will actually wait for the class 'collapsible' to be added to your DOM before being executed.

BTW, I would not produce a code which is relying on someone else's code: if you are not in control of the class 'collapsible' you are preparing your code for failure ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to get things done. This method will do the trick **providing that any resources to be loaded are returned as HTML**.

```
function load_content(p_rsrc)
  {
var l_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  l_request.addEventListener('readystatechanged', function(p_event) {
    if(this.readystate == 4)
// We wind up here once AJAX reports the request to be completed (either because of a timeout or because of a reaction from the server)
      if(this.status == 200)
        {
let l_col;
let l_target = document.getElementById('div-for-remote-content');
let l_this;

        if(l_target == null)
          {
          console.error('FATAL: Could not find container for remote content!');
          throw "internal error";
          }

// Assign the received contents to the container
// This clears out any previous content, including any event handlers, before adding the new content.
        l_target.innerHTML = l_request.responseText;
// Once we are here we can attach event handlers to any element that brings along the "collapsible" class...
// The following statement digs up all elements of the collapsible class that are present in their container.
        l_col = document.querySelectorAll('#div-for-remote-content .collapsible');

// Now dig through the entire list of items...
        for(l_this of l_col)
          {
          l_this.addEventListener("click", function(p_event) {
            p_event.target.classList.toggle("active");
            if (p_event.target.style.display === "block")
              p_event.target.style.display = "none";
            else
              p_event.target.style.display = "block";
            }, false);
          }
        }
// You can do some additional status handling here, like dealing with any errors
    }, false);
  l_request.open('GET', p_rsrc, true);
  l_request.send();
  }
```

As you can see the event listeners are attached outside of the scope of the loaded new content if and only if the AJAX request returned with a success (that is, status code 200). Any other status code won't allow the script to modify the contents of your container, and I have also added some rudimentary sanity checks.

Please note that assigning the contents (which have to be HTML to work properly) to `.innerHTML` clears out the DOM subtree of your container so that you can assign new content to it without having to worry about any event handlers or outdated DOM nodes. This avoids duplicate invocation of your event handler and also allows for attaching this function to a button as an event handler (or invocation from another script block). Please note that you have to pass the path to the desired resource to this function.

**EDIT:**

Corrected a bug in my code snippet

**EDIT 2:**

When you import this code into your document you need to make sure that it gets invoked whenever someone loads extra content into the document. You can do that by attaching a wrapper function to whatever mechanism is required to facilitate this (i. e. a button that triggers an event handler which in turn calls this function and also provides the URL of the resource to be loaded).

Once `load_content()` is called, the following sequence of events is set off:

- Create an XMLHttpRequest (required to perform an AJAX request for the desired resource).
- Attach an event handler to the XMLHttpRequest object that listens for ready state transitions (so we can determine when the response is available for use).
- Open the resource for retrieval. Please note that the third parameter is set to *true* to make this an asynchronous request.
- Send the request. The XMLHttpRequest immediately returns, but since we are listening for `readystatechange` events we detect once the request has been processed. In the meantime other things may be taken care of.
- Eventually the request is answered, the `readystatechange` event fires, and our request reports that the request has been completed (`this.readyState == 4`). This is our signal that we can begin processing the resource.
- Check whether the request has been successful (i. e. `this.status == 200`). If not, something has gone wrong and everything should be left untouched.
- Otherwise see whether the container exists. If not, log to the console and throw an exception (safeguard against an unknown element).
- Assign the response text to the `.innerHTML` of our container. The old content is discarded, and a new DOM subtree is constructed in said container.
- Get a list of all elements that belong to the `collapsible` class and reside in our container.
- For every element thus found repeat: Attach an event handler that listens for click events and which, when invoked, toggles the visibility of the elemet in question.

Any resources loaded from the remote source are not involved in this process at all so you don't risk multiple runs of this function, and every time that new content is loaded into the container, the old one is effectively overwritten.

Comment: I appreciated your help, the problem is bigger then I think at the beginning, and the main problem is - duplication, the original question was not been asked the right way, after rethinking my situation with this particular case and other possible future dev I came to a possible solution. Is it possible to check and run **specific** scripts again in the main script file after every successfully completed get request?

Comment: It is, and without incurring the issue of duplication. It's similar to what I have done here by attaching the code that sets any event handlers to the result of the AJAX request. Since it doesn't require you to load the script along with your remote resources, you don't risk that things would be duplicated.

Comment: I didn’t get you last comment, original problem from the beginning was that script from external file on main page didn’t run on remote content after loading, I just want to scripts from external file on main page works on newly added content to that page, if the previous answer is solving this somehow - I didn’t get it

Comment: O.k., then let me edit in the sequence of events - maybe that clarifies things.

Comment: The best thing to see whether it works for you is putting this code into your external JS file and hook the function up to any elements that load your external resources. The only thing that you have to ensure is passing the URL of the desired resource to the function.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: add listeners to '.collapsible' that are found in the fetched html and then add them to the document:

```
function addCollapsible(container /* $div1 in your code */ ) {
  [...container.querySelectorAll(".collapsible")].forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      const content = el.nextElementSibling;
      el.textContent = el.textContent.trim() === "collapse" ? "uncolapse" : "collapse";
      toggleDisplay(content);
    })
  })
}
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-js="fetch-html"]`)].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", async function(event) {
    const target = event.currentTarget;
    const url = target.getAttribute("data-url");
    const html = await fakeFetch(url);
    target.textContent = target.textContent.slice(target.textContent.indexOf("content"));
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.innerHTML = html;
    addCollapsible(container);
    target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', container)
  }, {
    once: true
  });
});

function addCollapsible(container) {
  [...container.querySelectorAll(".collapsible")].forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      const content = el.nextElementSibling;
      el.textContent = el.textContent.trim() === "collapse" ? "uncolapse" : "collapse";
      toggleDisplay(content);
    })
  })
}

function toggleDisplay(el) {
  if (!el.style.display || el.style.display === "block") {
    el.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
}

async function fakeFetch(url) {
  const urlMap = {
    "content1.html": content1Html,
    "content2.html": content2Html
  }

  await wait(200)
  return urlMap[url];
}

async function wait(waitTime) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, waitTime)
  })
}

const content1Html = `
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 1
</div>
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 2
</div>
`;

const content2Html = `
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 3
</div>
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 4
</div>
`;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<h2 data-js="fetch-html" data-url="content1.html">fetch content 1</h2>
<h2 data-js="fetch-html" data-url="content2.html">fetch content 2</h2>
```

### Solution 2: use event delegation:

```
/* use on document.body or even better the closets common ancestor: '#div-for-remote-content' */
document.body.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  const el = target.classList.contains("collapsible") ? target : target.closest(".collapsible");
  if (el) {
    const content = el.nextElementSibling;
      el.textContent = el.textContent.trim() === "collapse" ? "uncolapse" : "collapse";
      toggleDisplay(content);
  }
})
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-js="fetch-html"]`)].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", async function(event) {
    const target = event.currentTarget;
    const url = target.getAttribute("data-url");
    const html = await fakeFetch(url);
    target.textContent = target.textContent.slice(target.textContent.indexOf("content"));
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.innerHTML = html;
    target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', container)
  }, {
    once: true
  });
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
 const target = event.target;
  const el = target.classList.contains("collapsible") ? target : target.closest(".collapsible");
  if (el) {
   const content = el.nextElementSibling;
      el.textContent = el.textContent.trim() === "collapse" ? "uncolapse" : "collapse";
      toggleDisplay(content);
  }
})

function toggleDisplay(el) {
  if (!el.style.display || el.style.display === "block") {
    el.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
}

async function fakeFetch(url) {
  const urlMap = {
    "content1.html": content1Html,
    "content2.html": content2Html
  }

  await wait(200)
  return urlMap[url];
}

async function wait(waitTime) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, waitTime)
  })
}

const content1Html = `
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 1
</div>
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 2
</div>
`;

const content2Html = `
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 3
</div>
<div class="collapsible">
  collapse
</div>
<div>
  visible 4
</div>
`;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<h2 data-js="fetch-html" data-url="content1.html">fetch content 1</h2>
<h2 data-js="fetch-html" data-url="content2.html">fetch content 2</h2>
```

### Pro Tip:

To check how many listeners an element has, you can run `getEventListeners` on a given element in chrome console.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].map(el => 
    [el, getEventListeners(el)]
).filter(([_,o]) => Object.keys(o).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will keep looking for a specific class on a target element:

```
function checkElement(selector, cb) {
    var raf;
    var found = false;
    (function check() {
        const el = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (el) {
            found = true;
            cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
            // Do something here
            console.log('Found it');
            // Include your logic in the callBack
            cb();
        } else {
            raf = requestAnimationFrame(check);
        }
    })();
    return found;
}
```

How to use it:

```
checkElement('collapsibile', elementReady);

function elementReady() {
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
                content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                content.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
};
```

It acts like a "watcher". You can modify the `check` function of course as you see fit. Using `document.querySelector(selector);` will match only the first element in the DOM.

I'd use EventDelegation probably in your case but my understanding is that you are after something else.

Hope it helps anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Long answer short:

1) Don't be afraid of using jQuery, it's still one tiny good old legacy way for manipulating DOMs like what you are trying to achieve in your question.

2) You need to execute your snippet after "***loading from remote source***" completed.

```
$.get('t.html', {}, function (data) {
  var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
  var $div1 = $response.find('#div1');
  $('#div-for-remote-content').append($div1);
}, 'html').then(function () {
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for as I can't fully understand the issue you are having.

And thanks to the down voter who I guess hate jQuery, but I still insist jQuery is a useful library in 2018 even I didn't actually use it in the recent several projects.

Comment: Even if I put the script into every get call it still be causing duplicate problem